# How to do a select statement to claim relationship exist?

Tags: php, sql, oracle

External subject group

```
| pk | group_id | subid |
|----|----------|-------|
| 1  | 1        | s1    |
| 2  | 1        | s2    |
| 3  | 1        | s3    |
| 4  | 2        | x1    |
| 5  | 2        | x2    |
| 6  | 3        | y1    |
| 7  | 3        | y2    |
| 8  | 3        | y3    |
```

Internal subject group

```
| pk | group_id | subid |
|----|----------|-------|
| 1  | 1        | a1    |
| 2  | 1        | a2    |
| 3  | 1        | a3    |
| 4  | 2        | b1    |
| 5  | 3        | c1    |
| 5  | 3        | c2    |
| 7  | 3        | c3    |
| 8  | 3        | b4    |
```

I am using php and sql (oracle) at the moment. For example,
I have array of external subjects:

```
[s1, s2, s3]
```

I have array of internal subjects

```
[a1, a2, a3]
```

My attempt is that (incorrectly)

```
SELECT
  group_id
FROM
  external_subject_group e_s_g,
  internal_subject_group i_s_g
WHERE
  e_s_g.group_id = i_s_g.group_id AND
  e_s_g.subid = "s1" AND
  e_s_g.subid = "s2" AND
  e_s_g.subid = "s3" AND
  i_s_g.subid = "a1" AND
  i_s_g.subid = "b1" AND
  i_s_g.subid = "c1"


The group id either exist or empty.
```

Basically, I try to wrap this sql query into a php function. If the query returns the relationship id. I know the relationship `[s1, s2, s3] x [a1, a2, a3]` exist.

for example, another relationship is `[x1, x2] x [b1]`.

Comment: What is the definition of "relationship group_id == 1 exists"? Perhaps you think that's obvious, but I am not an imbecile, and it is not obvious to me, so you need to give more details. Make them precise, and don't expect an example to substitute for a proper definition.

Comment: Please provide more information, your question makes no sense right now.  Explain what your are looking for and an expected result of your query.  You do not know how to write the select, but you must have an idea of what you expect to see at the end.

Comment: sure, I will make it clear. Let me know if it is still not.

Comment: taking a stab in the dark; are you wanting to find the `group_id` from a list of `subid`s? I'm headed in the direction of `select group_id from ExternalSubjectGroupTableName where subid in('a1','a2','a3')`.  Or better yet, use the primary key.  Please note you wouldn't want to just stick variables in place of `a1` et al; you'd need to use prepared statements.

Comment: @TimMorton, Yes yes

Comment: @mathguy, I wrote down a select example. If it is still not clear, let me know

Comment: @Nic I wrote down a select example. If it is still not clear, let me know

Comment: Do you want to display the group id if it has all three External and Internal subjects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you want more than just a simple where condition, and that you are looking for a way to identify a group that has all 3 values. Here are a couple of alternative queries. The first is my best guess, the second is just for comparison and you can trial these examples at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bf8396/3)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (PK int, GROUP_ID int, SUBID varchar2(20))
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO Table1 (PK, GROUP_ID, SUBID)
         VALUES (1, 1, 's1')
    INTO Table1 (PK, GROUP_ID, SUBID)
         VALUES (2, 1, 's2')
    INTO Table1 (PK, GROUP_ID, SUBID)
         VALUES (3, 1, 's3')
    INTO Table1 (PK, GROUP_ID, SUBID)
         VALUES (4, 2, 'x1')
    INTO Table1 (PK, GROUP_ID, SUBID)
         VALUES (5, 2, 'x2')
    INTO Table1 (PK, GROUP_ID, SUBID)
         VALUES (6, 3, 'y1')
    INTO Table1 (PK, GROUP_ID, SUBID)
         VALUES (7, 3, 'y2')
    INTO Table1 (PK, GROUP_ID, SUBID)
         VALUES (8, 3, 'y3')
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

The following query uses GROUP BY and HAVING SUM(...) as a constct to require that ALL 3 wanted subid's MUST be used.

**Query 1**:

```
select group_id
from Table1
group by group_id
having SUM(case when subid in('s1','s2','s3') then 1 else 0 end) = 3
```

**[Result](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bf8396/3/0)**:

```
| GROUP_ID |
|----------|
|        1 |
```

**Query 2**:

This query only requires that ANY ONE of the subids listed have been used.

```
select distinct group_id
from Table1
where subid in('s1','s2','s3')
```

**[Result](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bf8396/3/1)**:

```
| GROUP_ID |
|----------|
|        1 |
```

+EDIT
You might also need to use UNION ALL

```
select group_id
from (
  select pk,group_id,subid from external_subject_group e_s_g
  UNION ALL
  select pk,group_id,subid from internal_subject_group i_s_g
  ) t1
group by group_id
having SUM(case when subid in('s1','s2','s3','a1','a2','a3') then 1 else 0 end) = 6
```